# ModuleNotFoundError on virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

After installing miniconda, my python modules stopped working, throwing **ModuleNotFoundError**. From what I can tell, miniconda changed my default environment settings. I checked both *.bash_profile* and *.bashrc* and updated the files to give conda the lowest priority. This fixed my default python version but didn't fix any of the broken modules.

Next I checked my PYTHONPATH with `python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"`. I discovered that the PYTHONPATH consisted entirely of conda python paths instead of the python version I had called. For reference, my default python version should be 3.8 (now set in *.bashrc*), and the conda version is 3.9.

```
['', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload']
```

I then manually changed my PYTHONPATH in the *.bashrc* file to include the appropriate library paths. After reloading *.bashrc*:

```
['', '/Users/Ghoti/venv/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload']
```

My modules now work! However, I haven't been able to figure out how to stop the conda 3.9 libraries from being appended to my PYTHONPATH. In addition, my printed python version is wrong.

```
Ghoti$ python --version
Python 3.9.6
Ghoti$ which python
/Users/Ghoti/venv/3.8/bin/python
```

I was able to "fix" my **ModuleNotFoundError** problem. However, the solution is only temporary. If I ever need to switch python version/environment, I'll have to go through the process again. I'd like to figure out what is overriding my PYTHONPATH, causing it to call conda 3.9 libraries, and fix the python version irregularity. I've considered that there might be a script/process running in the background, but I haven't found any related to conda/miniconda. I've also been looking for a python setting/config file. No luck. Any suggestions on where I should look?

**Edit** - Did some more digging. It looks like my version 3.8 python executable was entirely overwritten, and the only existing python installation that is version 3.9.6 is in my "/usr/bin". The two conda environments have versions "3.9.12" and "3.8.13". I feel more confident the issue isn't due to conda, but unsure what could have caused the problem.

***Final Edit***

I don't think the problem was miniconda. I did start having problems within a few days of using miniconda and I original assumed that it just took me a while to notice the issues. However, I now think that my virtual environment was created using a shared python. Problems were noticed on the same day that I connected to network. The shared python version changed, and that broke my environment. I don't have a solution to salvage the broken environment, but rebuilding it from scratch shouldn't take too long.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you only want to use conda when you explicitly need it, in other words, the default Python is the system Python.

If that's the case, you should disable the auto-activation of the base environment:

```bash
conda config --set auto_activate_base false

<restart shell>
```

Now you'll need to explicitly activate the conda environment before you can use the conda Python:

```bash
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug 11 2022, 13:49:25) [Clang 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ conda activate base
(base) $ python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Jun  1 2022, 06:36:29)
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```